# Cuda programming on a mac with Intel HD 4000

Tags: macos, cuda, intel

What do I have to do, to be able to do Cuda programming on a Macbook Air with Intel HD 4000 graphics?

Setup a virtual machine? Buy an external Nvidia card? Is it possible at all?

Comment: an nvidia technology on an Intel GPU? ^^ Use openCL..

Comment: That would lead me to this site, where there is only software for Windows and Red Hat + Suse. http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk . Virtual machine then?

Comment: Apple is also one of the main supporters for OpenCL. Try to check Xcode docs.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a new(-ish) Macbook Air you could perhaps use an external (NVidia) graphics device like this: 
[external Thunderbolt PCIe case](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/pci-express-graphics-thunderbolt,3263-2.html)

Otherwise it will not be possible to run Cuda programms on non NVidia Hardware (since it is a proprietary framework)

You may also be able to run Cuda code through converting it to OpenCL first (for example with this framework: [Swan Framwork](http://gpgpu.org/2010/03/09/swan) )